# Testing if a SVG file contains raster graphics

Tags: image-processing, svg

I am looking for a program that can test if a SVG file contains some raster graphics elements. Linux or Windows, CLI or GUI, and gratis if possible.

Comment: To test a few files or automatically batch test hundreds or thousands of them?

Answer (score 1):

You could modify [the program suggested here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/45614/1935) as follows:

```
using System;

namespace ExtractBitmapFromSvg
{
    static class ExtractBitmapFromSvg
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var svgFile = new SvgFile(args[0]);
            var images = svgFile.GetEmbeddedImages();
            var hasImages = images.Count > 0;
            Console.WriteLine(hasImages ? "images found" : "no images");
            return hasImages ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it's incomplete and does not identify all raster graphic types yet.